# A curious determinantal inequality I

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequalities, matrix-analysis, matrix-theory

Let $A, B$ be Hermitian matrices. Does the following hold?

$$\det(A^{2}+B^{2}+|AB+BA|)\leq \det(A^{2}+B^{2}+|AB|+|BA|)$$

As usual, $|X|=(X^*X)^{1/2}$. Clearly, quantities on both sides are no less than $\det(A+B)^2$.

Comment: What evidence or examples do you have that this is true; for example, with $2 \times 2$ matrices?

Comment: My evidence is weak, I could prove $\det(|AB+BA|)\leq \det(|AB|+|BA|)$... But I had run numerical experiments for the proposed inequality...

Comment: @M.Lin : Can we see the proof of $\det(|AB+BA|)\le\det(|AB|+|BA|)$? Interestingly, inequality $|AB+BA|\le |AB|+|BA|$ does not hold in general, whereas inequality $A^{2}+B^{2}+|AB+BA|\ge0$ seems to hold. Also, how do you show that both sides of your proposed inequality are no less than $\det(A+B)^2$?

Comment: @IosifPinelis As $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
|X| & X^{*} \\
X &  |X^{*}|\\
\end{array}
\right) $
is positive semidefinite (psd) for any $X$, it follows that
$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
|AB| & BA \\
AB & |BA| \\
\end{array}
\right)$ and
$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
|BA| & AB \\
BA & |AB| \\
\end{array}
\right)$ are psd. Adding them gives the positivity of $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
|AB|+|BA| & AB+BA \\
AB+BA & |AB|+|BA| \\
\end{array}
\right)$... $|\det (AB+BA)|=\det(|AB+BA|)\le\det(|AB|+|BA|)$ follows.

Comment: @M.Lin : Nice! It appears that the following stronger inequality holds for $n=2$ -- but not for $n=3$ (!): 
$\begin{bmatrix}|AB|+|BA|& |AB+BA|\\ |AB+BA|&|AB|+|BA|\end{bmatrix}\ge0$. Of course, for any Hermitian $M\ge0$, this inequality (when it holds) implies $\begin{bmatrix}M+|AB|+|BA|& M+|AB+BA|\\ M+|AB+BA|&M+|AB|+|BA|\end{bmatrix}\ge0$ and hence the inequality in question -- but, again, this would work only for $n=2$.

Comment: @DavidHandelman Iosif Pinelis gives a proof of $n=2$ case.

Comment: Didn't you want to also assume that $A$ and $B$ are positive definite?

Comment: @M.Lin : I wrote: "It appears that the following stronger inequality holds for $n=2$". That was based on some, rather extensive, numerical experiments. However, I don't have a proof of that. I am sorry if my comment was not clear enough.

Comment: @Suvrit Oh, yes, I should have put that condition.

Comment: Actually, I think even with that condition it does not hold.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the following matlab output:

> [image]

The square root function produces a very small imaginary error in the second case so I've just stripped that away in the final calculation. Therefore, the proposed determinantal inequality does not hold.

Comment: Exact calculations with Mathematica confirm that the proposed inequality does not hold for your $A$ and $B$. The difference between the right-hand side of that inequality and its left hand side is $-58.97\dots$.

Comment: It appears now that the inequality will likely hold only for $2\times2$ matrices. So, the proof for that case should be quite dimension-specific.

Comment: It took me a fair amount of tries before I got this pair which is why it becomes too hard to calculate by hand. That being said, I'm sure someone could find an easier pair.

Comment: @ChrisRamsey As Suvrit remarked, what if $A, B$ are assumed to be positive definite?

Comment: @ChrisRamsey thank you for your solution.

Comment: @M.Lin I think even with psd condition, one can immed. find a counterexample (if my matlab script is not wrong!)